# How does one find the parity trasformation matrix of spinors for non-free field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, parity

In many QFT textbook, for example, the book of Srednicki, they use free field theory to derive the transformation matrix of the Spinors:
$$P^{-1}\Psi(x)P=D(P)\Psi(P^{-1}x)$$

Then we have a relation:

$$D(P)=i\gamma_0$$
My question is:

Does the expression for $D(P)$   hold for the case where one has interation term in Lagrangian? If not, how can one derive the relation of the term like this using the above expression for $D(P)$ in arbitrary cases?
$$P^{-1}\bar{\Psi(x)}\Psi(x)P=\bar{\Psi(P^{-1}x)}\Psi(P^{-1}x)$$

Comment: Yes, the parity transformation is still defined that way in the interacting theory.

Comment: @knzhou So D(p) has nothing to do with the field?

Comment: @knzhou it’s natural to expect in different interaction the field transform differently right?

Comment: Do you have another definition for the field transformations in mind, that explicitly depends on the interaction strength? If so, what is it? (Not trying to be snarky here, but I really can't answer your question if you don't specify.)

Answer (score 0):

The way you deal with bilinear is just to insert unity of the form

\begin{align*}
P^{-1}\bar{\Psi}(x)\Psi(x)P &= P^{-1}\bar{\Psi}(x)P\cdot P^{-1}\Psi(x)P \\
&=\bar{\Psi}(t,-x)(-i\gamma^0)(i\gamma^0)\Psi(t,-x)\\
&=\bar{\Psi}(t,-x)\Psi(t,-x).
\end{align*}

where we have used the fact that $(\gamma^0)^2 = 1_4$, and the fact that

\begin{align*}
\bar{\Psi} = \Psi^\dagger\gamma^0 = (\gamma^0\Psi)^\dagger \stackrel{P}{\longmapsto} (\gamma^0i\gamma^0\Psi)^\dagger = \Psi^\dagger\gamma^0(-i\gamma^0) = \bar{\Psi}(-i\gamma^0).
\end{align*}

So the bilinear is invariant under parity.